# Logout after sharing [Xamarin.Android]

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, instagram, sharing

I am sharing image on instagram with code below. Is there any way to automaticially logout and back to my app after sharing? I want to do the same with facebook app.

```
        Intent intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
        if (intent != null)
        {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
            shareIntent.SetPackage("com.instagram.android");
            try
            {                    
                Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(_file);
                shareIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uri);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException f)
            {

            }
            shareIntent.SetType("image/jpeg");
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Log out what? The Instagram account? No.

Comment: Yes instagram account.